# Write file to a buffer

Tags: c

I'm trying to download a file with wget, then open it up, read it into a buffer and then send it through a socket to a server that is waiting for it. I've successfully been able to download the file and then open it up but then something goes wrong when I try to read it into the buffer. The file that I'm trying to download is 8000ish bytes long but when I write it to the buffer and then run sizeof(fileBuffer) it's only reporting a size of 8 bytes. Here is the code:

```
    //open the file
    if((downloadedFile = fopen(fileName, "rb"))==NULL){
      perror("Downloaded file open");
    }
    //determine file size
    fseek(downloadedFile, 0L, SEEK_END);
    downloadedFileSize = ftell(downloadedFile);
    fseek(downloadedFile, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    printf("%s %d \n", "downloadedFileSizse = ",downloadedFileSize);

    //send back length of file
    if (send(acceptDescriptor, &downloadedFileSize, sizeof(long), 0) == -1){
      perror("send downloaded file size Length");
      exit(0);
    }

    //start by loading file into the buffer
    char *fileBuffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*downloadedFileSize);
    int bytesRead = fread(fileBuffer,sizeof(char), downloadedFileSize, downloadedFile);
    printf("%s %d \n","bytesRead: ", bytesRead);
    printf("sizeof(fileBuffer) Send back to SS: %d\n",sizeof(fileBuffer));
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 8907 (8.7K) [text/html]
Saving to: âindex.htmlâ

100%[======================================>] 8,907       --.-K/s   in 0s

2013-10-13 09:35:16 (158 MB/s) - âindex.htmlâ saved [8907/8907]

downloadedFileSizse =  8907
bytesRead:  8907
sizeof(fileBuffer) Send back to SS: 8
bytesLeft:  0
n:  8907
```

When I run the fread it's reading 8907 bytes but for some reason it's not writing them to the buffer correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fileBuffer` is a character pointer, so `sizeof` will report the size of the character pointer, not the size of the buffer. The return value of `fread` is the number of bytes written to the buffer so use `bytesRead` for the size of the buffer.

Comment: OK, thanks. So it seems that it is getting written to the buffer correctly then.

Comment: Buffer was functioning fine. Thanks for the help.